# Get value in v-for loop into methods in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
<form method="post" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
       <div class="image-upload" v-for="(item, index) in uploadVal" :key="item._id">
          <label class="btn btn-sm btn-success">
              <a-icon type="upload" />Upload
              <input
                type="file"
                ref="file"
                accept="image/*"
                @change="handleClickUpload"
                style="display: none;"
              />
        </label>
        <div class="show-img">
            <img :src="getImageURL(item.url)" />
        </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

In methods:

```
methods: {
   handleClickUpload(e) {
      console.log(e.target.files);
   },
}
```

I am doing upload image in vuejs. And I want to get the `index` value of the v-for loop under the `handleClickUpload` of the methods. Is there any way to get `index` in `handleClickUpload` ? Please give me ideas.Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a function to it and pass the `event` and `index` externally as:

```
<input
  type="file"
  ref="file"
  accept="image/*"
  @change="(e) => handleClickUpload(e, index)"
  style="display: none"
/>
```

**Live Demo**

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

and get the index in the function `handleClickUpload` as:

```
handleClickUpload(e, i) {
  console.log(e.target.files);
  console.log(i);
},
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
@change="handleClickUpload($event, index)"
```

```
methods: {
  handleClickUpload(e, i) {
    console.log(e.target.files, i);
  },
}
```